# bar chart - 'inner' x ticks?

Tags: bar-chart

i've successfully created my first 'bar chart' today:

[image]

by the use of the code given below:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                         
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                            
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{units}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10, 
        saeule-style/.style={
          title={\textbf{Bar Chart}},
        },
        height=6cm,
        width=20cm,
        grid=major,
        grid style={
          solid,
          ultra thin,
          gray
        },
        xmin=1925,
        xmax=1975,
        xtick={1925,1930,...,1975},
        x tick label style={
            rotate=90
        },
        x tick style={
          color=black,
          thin
        },
        ymin=0,
        ymax=10,
        y tick style={
          color=black,
          thin
        },
        xlabel={\textbf{Year}},
      ylabel={\textbf{Population}},
      legend columns=2,     
        legend style={
            font=\scriptsize,
            legend pos=north west,
            draw=none,
            /tikz/column 2/.style={
        column sep=10pt,
      }
        },
      ybar=5pt,
      nodes near coords,
      /pgf/number format/.cd,
      use comma,
      set thousands separator={},
} 


\begin{document}     

 \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[saeule-style]
        \addplot[ybar, bar width=0.2cm, fill=blue, draw=black] coordinates {(1930,5) (1940,3) (1950,4) (1960,5) (1970,7)};
            \addplot[ybar, bar width=0.2cm, fill=red, draw=black] coordinates {(1930,3) (1940,4)    (1950,4) (1960,4) (1970,6)};

            \legend{Far,Near}
    \end{axis} 
 \end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I added those x- and ytics. As I expected, the ytics were drawn *in* the diagram. Unfortunately, the xtics don't. It seems that something gave them a kind of "outer"-option.

Does anyone of you know how I can place them also *in* the diagram?

Thank you in advance,
  eniem

---

EDIT: Hmm ... now tried to use the 'xtick align=inside'-option, but it doesn't work. Does anybody know why?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1pt]{standalone}     
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                     
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}                  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                            
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{units}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, 
        saeule-style/.style={
          title={\textbf{Bar Chart}},
        },
        height=6cm,
        width=20cm,
        grid=major,
        grid style={
          solid,
          ultra thin,
          gray
        },
        xmin=1925,
        xmax=1975,
        xtick={1925,1930,...,1975},
        xtick align=inside,
        xticklabel style={
            rotate=90
        },
        xtick style={
          color=black,
          thin
        },
        ymin=0,
        ymax=10,
        ytick align=inside,
        y tick style={
          color=black,
          thin
        },
        xlabel={\textbf{Year}},
      ylabel={\textbf{Population}},
      legend columns=2,     
        legend style={
            font=\scriptsize,
            legend pos=north west,
            draw=none,
            /tikz/column 2/.style={
        column sep=10pt,
      }
        },
      ybar=5pt,
      /pgf/number format/.cd,
      use comma,
      set thousands separator={},
} 


\begin{document} 

 \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[saeule-style]
        \addplot[ybar, bar width=6pt, fill=blue, draw=black] coordinates {(1930,5) (1940,3) (1950,4) (1960,5) (1970,7)};
        \addlegendentry{Far}
            \addplot[ybar, bar width=6pt, fill=red, draw=black] coordinates {(1930,3) (1940,4)  (1950,4) (1960,4) (1970,6)};
            \addlegendentry{Near}
        \end{axis} 
 \end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!
 eniem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the manual for `ybar`;

> It changes the legend, draws ticks outside of the axis lines and draws multiple \addplot arguments adjacent to each other;....

So it expected. You can override this via small adjustments though, `xtick align=inside` will do it automatically for you as @Jake reminded in the comment.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10, 
        xtick={1925,1930,...,1975},
        x tick label style={rotate=90,xshift=-4mm},
        ybar=5pt,
        xtick style={/pgfplots/major tick length=-2mm,draw=black,thick}
} 


\begin{document}     

 \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[ybar, bar width=0.2cm, fill=blue, draw=black] coordinates {(1930,5) (1940,3) (1950,4) (1960,5) (1970,7)};
            \addplot[ybar, bar width=0.2cm, fill=red, draw=black] coordinates {(1930,3) (1940,4)    (1950,4) (1960,4) (1970,6)};
    \end{axis} 
 \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or you could set `xtick align=inside`, of course `=)`

Comment: @Jake Pfff,...are you reading the manual secretly? :P

Comment: @Jake thanks for your answer. - I tried out to use `xtick align=inside` like I added in my first question above. Unfortunately it doesn't work. And I don't know why. Maybe you could help me ...

Comment: @eniem Did you try putting it after `ybar=5pt`?

Comment: @eniem: As percusse said, you need to put `xtick align=inside` *after* `ybar=5pt`, since the `ybar` option calls (among other things) `xtick align=outside`, which overwrites the previous `xtick align` option.